# CUDA to OpenCL : What is the equivalent of (blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.x) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x in OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, opencl

I'm a beginner in OpenCL, trying to convert a simple CUDA function to OpenCL. In the CUDA function they've used the below snippet to get the index of operations,

```
int id = (blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y*gridDim.x) * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

Is get_global_id(0) the equivalent of the above in OpenCL?

```
int id = get_global_id(0);
```

Comment: The short answer is no. Did you have something more than a yes/no answer in mind?

Comment: @talonmies If no, I would like to find an alternative approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CUDA (only OpenCL), but it looks like the following are equivalent:

- `get_group_id(uint dimindx)` and `blockIdx.[xyz]`
- `get_local_size(uint dimindx)` and `blockDim.[xyz]`
- `get_local_id(uint dimindx)` and `threadIdx.[xyz]`
- `get_num_groups(uint dimindx)` and `gridDim.[xyz]`

Where `dimindx` is 0, 1, or 2, corresponding to `.x`, `.y`, or `.z` respectively.

`get_global_id(0)` is the same as `get_group_id(0) * get_local_size(0) + get_local_id(0)`, so assuming the above equivalences are indeed correct, it would be the same as `blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x`. (And equivalently for index 1 with .y, and index 2 with .z)

To get the same ID value, I think you probably want something like this:

```
int id = get_group_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0);
```

Note that the original CUDA code explicitly does not take into account the `threadIdx.y`. I suspect this might be because your `blockDim.y` is 1, or because you're genuinely trying to get at the top-most item within the block (not the one corresponding to the current thread).

A more common scenario is probably to get the index for the current work-item into an array in a buffer containing an array of 2D elements:

```
int id = get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0);
```

This is of course equivalent to the previous expression if `get_local_size(1)` is 1. (Blocks have height 1.)

All of the above assumes that you've enqueued your kernels with equivalent workgroup (block) and global dimensions as in CUDA.

Comment: I'm not sure your last expression is correct, `get_global_id(1)` should probably be `get_group_id(1)`

Comment: @talonmies Looks like you're right on deeper inspection of the question. I'll fix it - although I suspect block size might be 1 in the y direction in the asker's case, otherwise it seems an odd thing to get an ID for.

Comment: @talonmies I suspect `get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0)` is something that's going to be more useful to others, so I've added an explanation to that effect as well as correcting the original one.